# download the img file of Ubuntu touch

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-touch

I want to download the img file of Ubuntu touch to convert it to vdi and use it on virtual box or directly use it with limbo on android.

Also I checked some answers and websites and all of them said it's on get Ubuntu touch page on official Ubuntu touch website but I could not find it.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer ?

Comment: Even a little help

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Touch](https://ubuntu-touch.io/get-ubuntu-touch) is available for some particular mobile phones, but there is no such installer for desktops.

However, the Ubuntu Unity will soon offer a "Lomiri" (Lomiri/Unity8 is the UI for Ubuntu touch) variant. Keep an eye [their blog](https://ubuntuunity.org/posts/ubuntu-unity-2310-released/) for more details.

Comment: It wasn't answer of my question I wanted to know where is the img download link

Comment: The answer is, there is none

Comment: Really ? So why some guys and bing chat talk about it